# Add Legend in negativeSeries bar chart

Tags: jqplot

I want to add legend for both positive values and negative values like the image attached.How can I achieve this? Please help me.

My Tried Code is   [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xKL2w/7/)

```
 xSeries = [["a", -1], ["b", 2], ["c", -3], ["d", 5]];
        var barChartOptions = {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                barDirection: 'vertical',
                barWidth:10,
                varyBarColor: true,
            },
            fillToZero: true,
            fillAxis: 'x',
            pointLabels: {
               // show: true
            },
            pointLabels : {
                show : true,
                hideZeros : true,
                location  : 's',
                ypadding  : 12
            }
        },
        legend : {
            show : true,
            placement : 'outsideGrid',       
            fontFamily : 'OpenSans-Regular',
            marginTop : '100px',
            textColor : '#414141',
            rowSpacing : '14px',
            border : 'none',
            background : 'transparent'
        },
        series : [{
            label : "Greater",
            lineWidth : 1,
            // Use (open) circlular markers.
            markerOptions : {
                style : "filledCircle"
            }
        }],
        seriesColors: ["#7DAB0B"],
        negativeSeriesColors: ["#D99F03"],
        axes:{
            yaxis:{
                renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
                fontFamily : 'OpenSans-Regular',
                label : "kWh",
                    textColor : '#414141',
                    tickOptions : {
                        show : true,
                        fontFamily : 'OpenSans-Regular',
                        textColor : '#414141',
                        fontSize : '10pt'
                    }
            },
            xaxis:{         
                label : "Date",
                renderer : $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                labelRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                //renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                fontFamily : 'OpenSans-Regular',
                    textColor : '#414141',
                    tickOptions : {
                        angle : -60,
                        show : true,
                        fontFamily : 'OpenSans-Regular',
                        textColor : '#414141',
                        fontSize : '10pt'
                    }
            },
        },
        grid : {
                background : 'transparent',
                gridLineColor : '#c5c5c5'
            }
    };
    try {       
            var plotBarChart = $.jqplot("chart1",  [xSeries], barChartOptions);     
        } catch (e) {
            // alert(e);
        }
```

[image: Legend]

Comment: Is your fiddle really complete?

Comment: @felipe.zkn yes. I want to add legend like the image attached

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code follows [this](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html) format.

also be sure to include `jquery.jqplot.css`

include it: `<script src="https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/raw/e8af8a37f0f14ea1e8c630ecfe6f1b1933794036/src/jquery.jqplot.css"></script>`

Or copy the following code into your `css` file:

```
//jquery.jqplot.css
    /*rules for the plot target div.  These will be cascaded down to all plot elements         according to css rules*/
     .jqplot-target {
    position: relative;
    color: #666666;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    /*    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;*/
    }
    /*rules applied to all axes*/
     .jqplot-axis {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    }
    .jqplot-xaxis {
    margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .jqplot-x2axis {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .jqplot-yaxis {
    margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .jqplot-y2axis, .jqplot-y3axis, .jqplot-y4axis, .jqplot-y5axis, .jqplot-y6axis, .jqplot-y7axis, .jqplot-y8axis, .jqplot-y9axis, .jqplot-yMidAxis {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
/*rules applied to all axis tick divs*/
 .jqplot-axis-tick, .jqplot-xaxis-tick, .jqplot-yaxis-tick, .jqplot-x2axis-tick, .jqplot-y2axis-tick, .jqplot-y3axis-tick, .jqplot-y4axis-tick, .jqplot-y5axis-tick, .jqplot-y6axis-tick, .jqplot-y7axis-tick, .jqplot-y8axis-tick, .jqplot-y9axis-tick, .jqplot-yMidAxis-tick {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: pre;
}
.jqplot-xaxis-tick {
    top: 0px;
    /* initial position untill tick is drawn in proper place */
    left: 15px;
    /*    padding-top: 10px;*/
    vertical-align: top;
}
.jqplot-x2axis-tick {
    bottom: 0px;
    /* initial position untill tick is drawn in proper place */
    left: 15px;
    /*    padding-bottom: 10px;*/
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.jqplot-yaxis-tick {
    right: 0px;
    /* initial position untill tick is drawn in proper place */
    top: 15px;
    /*    padding-right: 10px;*/
    text-align: right;
}
.jqplot-yaxis-tick.jqplot-breakTick {
    right: -20px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding:1px 5px 1px 5px;
    /*    background-color: white;*/
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.jqplot-y2axis-tick, .jqplot-y3axis-tick, .jqplot-y4axis-tick, .jqplot-y5axis-tick, .jqplot-y6axis-tick, .jqplot-y7axis-tick, .jqplot-y8axis-tick, .jqplot-y9axis-tick {
    left: 0px;
    /* initial position untill tick is drawn in proper place */
    top: 15px;
    /*    padding-left: 10px;*/
    /*    padding-right: 15px;*/
    text-align: left;
}
.jqplot-yMidAxis-tick {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.jqplot-xaxis-label {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    position: absolute;
}
.jqplot-x2axis-label {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    position: absolute;
}
.jqplot-yaxis-label {
    margin-right: 10px;
    /*    text-align: center;*/
    font-size: 11pt;
    position: absolute;
}
.jqplot-yMidAxis-label {
    font-size: 11pt;
    position: absolute;
}
.jqplot-y2axis-label, .jqplot-y3axis-label, .jqplot-y4axis-label, .jqplot-y5axis-label, .jqplot-y6axis-label, .jqplot-y7axis-label, .jqplot-y8axis-label, .jqplot-y9axis-label {
    /*    text-align: center;*/
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
.jqplot-meterGauge-tick {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    color: #999999;
}
.jqplot-meterGauge-label {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #999999;
}
table.jqplot-table-legend {
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
table.jqplot-table-legend, table.jqplot-cursor-legend {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
td.jqplot-table-legend {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
/*
These rules could be used instead of assigning
element styles and relying on js object properties.
*/

/*
td.jqplot-table-legend-swatch {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

tr.jqplot-table-legend:first td.jqplot-table-legend-swatch {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
*/
 td.jqplot-seriesToggle:hover, td.jqplot-seriesToggle:active {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.jqplot-table-legend .jqplot-series-hidden {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
div.jqplot-table-legend-swatch-outline {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding:1px;
}
div.jqplot-table-legend-swatch {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-top-width: 5px;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    border-left-width: 6px;
    border-right-width: 6px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
}
.jqplot-title {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
table.jqplot-cursor-tooltip {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
.jqplot-cursor-tooltip {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: rgba(208, 208, 208, 0.5);
    padding: 1px;
}
.jqplot-highlighter-tooltip, .jqplot-canvasOverlay-tooltip {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: rgba(208, 208, 208, 0.5);
    padding: 1px;
}
.jqplot-point-label {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    z-index: 2;
}
td.jqplot-cursor-legend-swatch {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
div.jqplot-cursor-legend-swatch {
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 0.7em;
}
.jqplot-error {
    /*   Styles added to the plot target container when there is an error go here.*/
    text-align: center;
}
.jqplot-error-message {
    /*    Styling of the custom error message div goes here.*/
    position: relative;
    top: 46%;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.jqplot-bubble-label {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    /*    background: rgba(90%, 90%, 90%, 0.15);*/
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    color: rgb(20%, 20%, 20%);
}
div.jqplot-bubble-label.jqplot-bubble-label-highlight {
    background: rgba(90%, 90%, 90%, 0.7);
}
div.jqplot-noData-container {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(96%, 96%, 96%, 0.3);
    }
```